# Fast and economic File Transfer in dot Net?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, compact-framework

I want to make a fast File Transfer between normal dotnet framework and compact framework (mobile Device in wireless LAN). The Server is located somewhere in germany and the Clients are located in different cities. I want to Transfer sqlite-databases with size of 3 to 20mb.

How can this be done very fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I achieved this with a filestream which is directly converted to a gzip stream and then goes Into a networkstream. On client-side the networkstream will be read Into a filestream over the gzip stream. Also I VACUUM the database before transferring it.